# Storing WPF button click counter value in SQL database?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF button with a textbox under which records names.

The names need to be jumbled on button press, how?

Comment: 'the value' is reset when leaving... --- what value?

Comment: Do you mean `... SET [Value] = [Value] + @nm WHERE ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If

> The aim is that the counter value inserted into the database is added to the previous value rather than creating a new one.

Then, you need to change your query to add to the existing value instead of overwriting it.  So it should be `[Value] = [Value] + @nm` as shown below:

```
UPDATE [CounterValues] SET [Value] = [Value] + @nm WHERE [CounterName] = @CounterName;";
```